# How to remove data duplicate in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php problem, I like to make the result as below:

123*thomas*Tiffany*Catherine*EnEn*Gabriel*Elizabeth*Ah Goh*

but the result given as below:

123*123*123*123*123*thomas*thomas*thomas*thomas*Tiffany*Tiffany*Tiffany*Tiffany*Catherine*Catherine*Catherine*Catherine*Catherine*EnEn*EnEn*EnEn*EnEn*Gabriel*Gabriel*Gabriel*Gabriel*Elizabeth*Elizabeth*Elizabeth*Elizabeth*Ah Goh*Ah Goh*Ah Goh*Ah Goh*Ah Goh*

Anyone can tell me how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
$name = $_POST['Username'];

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM User");                 
$data1 = mysql_query("SELECT Friends.responseRequest FROM User INNER JOIN Friends ON 
            User.username = Friends.sentRequest WHERE User.username = '$name' AND     Friends.status = 'approved'")or die(mysql_error());; 

$data2=mysql_query("SELECT Friends.sentRequest FROM User INNER JOIN Friends ON User.username = Friends.responseRequest WHERE User.username = '$name'
                 AND Friends.status = 'approved'");   


    $user = array();
    while($info1 = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
    array_push($user, $info1[username]);
    }

$friend =array();
     $getFriend1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Friends WHERE sentRequest='$name' AND status='approved'");
     $getFriend2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Friends WHERE responseRequest='$name' AND status='approved'"); 

     while($info2 = mysql_fetch_array($getFriend1)){
    array_push($friend , $info2[responseRequest]);
    }

     while($info3 = mysql_fetch_array($getFriend2)){
    array_push($friend , $info3[sentRequest]);
    }

    $newFriend = array_unique($friend);
    $newUser=array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($user);$i++){
        for($j=0;$j<count($newFriend);$j++){
            if($newFriend[$j]!=$user[$i]&&$user[$i]!=$name){
                echo $user[$i]."*";
            }
        }

    }

    mysql_close();
```

Comment: I haven't looked much into the code. But I have a feeling you could have used `DISTINCT` in your SQL Query to less complicate the logic.

Comment: this code is very difficult to grasp. What you should really do is take a good look into the database table structure and start working on a single query that gets all the information you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy way (not necessarily the best) is to split the result into an array, eliminate the duplicates and then join the parts again.

```
<?php
$str = '123*123*123*123*123*thomas*thomas*thomas*thomas*Tiffany*Tiffany*Tiffany*Tiffany*Catherine*Catherine*Catherine*Catherine*Catherine*EnEn*EnEn*EnEn*EnEn*Gabriel*Gabriel*Gabriel*Gabriel*Elizabeth*Elizabeth*Elizabeth*Elizabeth*Ah Goh*Ah Goh*Ah Goh*Ah Goh*Ah Goh*';
$aux = array_unique(explode('*', $str));
$str = implode('*', $aux);
```